# NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

Uma pessoa está lançar uma proposta, e encontrei através do IDErro gerado na pagina que ela está acessando esse erro abaixo. Mas não consigo entender o motivo dele, podem me ajduar?

```
    PCA.Framework.PCAException: PCA Unexpected Exception: PCA Unexpected Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ---> 
    PCA.Framework.PCAException: PCA Unexpected Exception: PCA Unexpected Exception: PCA Unexpected Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ---> 
    PCA.Framework.PCAException: PCA Unexpected Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ---> 
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     
    at MetLife.Cotador.Business.DocumentoUploadPendenciaBusiness.ObtemTokenAutenticacaoMorpheus(Int32 numSeqCorretor, String nomeCorretor) in C:\PCACodeGit\MetLife.CotadorUX\MetLife.Cotador.Business\DocumentoUploadPendenciaBusiness.cs:line 242     
    at MetLife.Cotador.Business.DocumentoUploadPendenciaBusinessInjection.ObtemTokenAutenticacaoMorpheus(Int32 , String )     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     
    at MetLife.Cotador.Business.DocumentoUploadPendenciaBusinessInjection.ObtemTokenAutenticacaoMorpheus(Int32 , String )     
    at MetLife.Cotador.Business.DocumentoUploadPendenciaBusiness.VerificaDocumentoPendencia(Nullable`1 idCotacao) in C:\PCACodeGit\MetLife.CotadorUX\MetLife.Cotador.Business\DocumentoUploadPendenciaBusiness.cs:line 283    
    at MetLife.Cotador.Business.DocumentoUploadPendenciaBusinessInjection.VerificaDocumentoPendencia(Nullable`1 )     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     
at MetLife.Cotador.Business.DocumentoUploadPendenciaBusinessInjection.VerificaDocumentoPendencia(Nullable`1 )     
    at MetLife.Cotador.Business.PropostaBusiness.Transmite(Int32 idCotacao) in C:\PCACodeGit\MetLife.CotadorUX\MetLife.Cotador.Business\PropostaBusiness.cs:line 739     at MetLife.Cotador.Business.PropostaBusinessInjection.Transmite(Int32 )     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     
    at MetLife.Cotador.Business.PropostaBusinessInjection.Transmite(Int32 )     
    at MetLife.Cotador.UX.Areas.Api.Controllers.CotacaoController.Transmite(Int32 idCotacao) in C:\PCACodeGit\MetLife.CotadorUX\MetLife.Cotador.UX\Areas\Api\Controllers\CotacaoController.cs:line 179     
    at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )     
    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)     
    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)     
    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()     
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()     
    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()     
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()     
    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()     
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()     
    at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()     
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()     
    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Maniero, também não tenho muita rastreabilidade sobre o erro, por ter recuperado dele atraves de um cod gerado na tela.

Comment: Pela mensagem de exceção, só se tem a informação que o método `DocumentoUploadPendenciaBusiness.ObtemTokenAutenticacaoMorpheus(Int32 numSeqCorretor, String nomeCorretor)` lançou exceção em C:\PCACodeGit\MetLife.CotadorUX\MetLife.Cotador.Business\DocumentoUploadPendenciaBusiness.cs, linha 242.